# How can I use ScenicView to inspect Subwindows (ContextMenus, PopupControls, etc)

Tags: debugging, javafx, scenegraph

Using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/), I want to be able to inspect things like [`ContextMenu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html)s or the insides of a [`ComboBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html), but (as they should) they disappear before said inspection can happen:

[image: Unable to inspect using ScenicView]

Apart from changing the behavior of each control to not disappear, is there a way to freeze things so that these kind of controls can be inspected with SceneBuilder?

**[Here's a SSCCE](https://github.com/TurekBot/ScenicView-Freeze)**, to give anyone willing a jump start.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old but I also ran into this issue. I have a partial answer:

```
contextMenu.autoHideProperty().set(false);
```

Will make it so that the menu stays up. But, it seems that ScenicView will refuse to actually inspect the menu...

There is an bug inside SecenicView which is why it does not inspect the SubWindows.

https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view/issues/18